# Using addeventlistener to add content when radio button is clicked in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, radio-button, addeventlistener

I am a freshman at a university. I have been given an assignement where I need to use addEventListener. The problem is that I haven't used it before.

What this assignment is, is that I have a json file With a list of student names. My first exercise was to show a list of all the students. I did that. But then comes the hard part, where I can't find a possible solution, when I need to show only students that are in a certain program. There are radio buttons for each of the programs and when clicked a list of the members of the program need to show up. Also there is a radio button that says "all", which need to Select all the students.

Here is my javascript file:

```
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
})
  .then(function appendData(data) {
  var unordered = document.querySelector(".studenter");
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.innerHTML = 'Name: ' + data[i].fornavn + ' ' + data[i].etternavn;
    unordered.appendChild(li);
  }
});
```

Here is the HTML file:

```
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Studenter i IIKG1002 og IDG1011</title>
    <script defer src="js/studenterIKlasse.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/studenterIKlasse.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Studenter i IIKG1002 og IDG1011</h1>
    <p>Velg klasse</p>
    <div class="klasseVelger">
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="programvelger" id="BIGEOMAT" />
        <label for="BIGEOMAT">Bachelor in Engineering, Geomatics</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="programvelger" id="BWU" />
        <label for="BWU">Bachelor in Web Development</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="programvelger" id="ÅRWEB" />
        <label for="ÅRWEB">Web Design - One-year programme</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="programvelger" id="BIXD" />
        <label for="BIXD">Interaction Design - Bachelor's Programme</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="radio" name="programvelger" id="all" />
        <label for="all">Show all</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>
    <ul class="studenter"></ul>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is an example of what the student Object look like (json):

```
{
  "fornavn": "Marcus Gimse",
  "etternavn": "Blikstad",
  "studieprogram": "Bachelor in Engineering, Geomatics",
  "forkortelse": "BIGEOMAT"
},
```

Comment: `const radButtons = document.getElementsByName('programvelger'), studenter = document.querySelector('.studenter'); for(let i=0,l=radButtons.length; i<l; i++){ radButtons[i].addEventListener('change', function(){ studenter.textContent = this.value; }); }`

Comment: I tried your solution but all I got when I clicked on the radio buttons was the string "on".

Comment: Oh, yeah, give you radio inputs a value.

Comment: I tried this: var BIGEOMAT = document.getElementById.("BIGEOMAT").value but it didn't work.

Comment: No, that's just assigning the value to a var, which would be `''` since you never assign a value to the Element in the first place. You want to give values to the HTML `<input />`s, or to the Element you get with JavaScript.